# save time in backup path of rsnapshot

Tags: backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I want to use rsnapshot for backuping my local system to an external disk. Since now I used a plane rsync command for creating hardlinked backup folders with names like `2018-10-15_12:23`. I configured rsnapshot for manual backup and now it creates folders like `manual.0` etc.

Is there any way to make rsnapshot creating backup folders like I used before? I bet, the answer is no, because thats the way rsnapshot works and structures its data. But if there is any ideas for this, I would be happy to know more

Answer (score 1):

looks like this wrapper script can solve the problem:

https://github.com/kmccormick/rsnapshot-timestamp